# Use Liferay theme css in Portlets

Tags: liferay, portlet, portal, liferay-theme

I would like to define all our styles in a the custom Liferay theme we developed. I want to know if it is possible to use css classes defined in the theme in portlets project. We need to avoid duplicate css files in every portlet project. The aim is that the theme controls all look and feel aspects of our portlets and so if we change the theme (or deploy portlets in another portal container) portlet styles change.
You think this is possible ?

Thanks in advance ..

Comment: Yes, that is how theme works in Liferay. You can use css classes in portlet which are defined in theme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do **is** the recommended way to style both the theme and the Portlets.

Portlet styles should only be affect the layout within the Portlet it belongs. All other styles; colors, fonts, etc., should be defined in the theme's `custom.css`.

I would advise you to try styling the existing Portlet classes before introducing new ones. Then, if you're really stuck, edit `portlet.vm`.

Take a look at [Liferay's Political Theme](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-plugins/blob/6.2.x/themes/zoe-political-theme/docroot/_diffs/css/custom.css#L237-L243):

```
custom.css

...

.portlet {
    margin-bottom: 10px;

    .portlet-topper {
        padding: 0;

        .portlet-title {
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Is it mandatory to have a custom.css (named so) in the custom theme ? 
If I understood correctly, I can define css classes in theme and in my portlet project I can simply put these classes in the jsps ?

Comment: Hi! I've found the answer. it is possible to rename custom.css file or have many css files as needed. To use a particular one we need to mention it in liferay-look-and-feel.properties in the required theme tag as below:
`<color-scheme id="01" name="A-Class">
     <default-cs>true</default-cs>
     <css-class>cssFileName</css-class>
 </color-scheme>`

Here suppose we defined a css file named cssFileName.css.
Thanks again for your answer..It allowed me to understand portlet/theme interaction.